# How to create a form dynamically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I want to create a invisible form anywhere into a HTML page dynamically using JavaScript and then submit automatically.
I want to create the form given below:

```
<form name='myForm' method='post' action='http://www.another_page.com/index.htm'>
<input type='text' name='myInput' value='Values of my input'>
<input type='hidden1' value='Hidden value 1'>
<input type='hidden2' value='Hidden value 2'>
</form>
```

I tried using the JavaScript below:

```
my_form=document.createElement('FORM');
my_form.name='myForm';
my_form.method='POST';
my_form.action='http://www.another_page.com/index.htm';
my_tb=document.createElement('INPUT');
my_tb.type='TEXT';
my_tb.name='myInput';
my_tb.value='Values of my Input';
my_tb.appendChild(my_form);
document.body.add(my_form,document.body.elements[0]);
document.my_form.submit();
```

But not working? How can I do that? Please help.

Comment: Probably you should just use `.innerHTML`...

Comment: The problem with .innerHTML is when you try to submit the form.  You won't have a reference to the form, and it may not have been added to the DOM.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're adding the form element as a child of the text box.

```
my_tb.appendChild(my_form);
```

Should be

```
my_form.appendChild(my_tb);
```

Also, I don't see where you're trying to create the hidden elements, but it's the same thing as adding a text box.

Another problem - trying to reference the form as document.xxx means that xxx is the *name* of the form.  But anyway, try

```
my_form=document.createElement('FORM');
my_form.name='myForm';
my_form.method='POST';
my_form.action='http://www.another_page.com/index.htm';

my_tb=document.createElement('INPUT');
my_tb.type='TEXT';
my_tb.name='myInput';
my_tb.value='Values of my Input';
my_form.appendChild(my_tb);

my_tb=document.createElement('INPUT');
my_tb.type='HIDDEN';
my_tb.name='hidden1';
my_tb.value='Values of my hidden1';
my_form.appendChild(my_tb);
document.body.appendChild(my_form);
my_form.submit();
```

Comment: Beated me! from a few secs :) +1

Answer (score 3):

You also can do the Saurabh Chauhan response but without add the dinamic element to body
This solution is all dinamic solution.

```
    var myform = document.createElement("form");
    myform.action = "myForm.aspx";
    myform.method = "post";


    product = document.createElement("input");
    product.value = "value";
    product.name = "name";

    myform.appendChild(product);
    myform.submit();
```

Comment: the `submit()` is not performed if the `myform` is not appended to the `document.body`. As soon as I add `document.body.appendChild(myform);`, your code works too.

Answer (score 2):

```
              var myform = document.createElement("form");

                product = document.createElement("input");
                product.value = JSProduct;
                product.name = "Product";
                myform.action = "myForm.aspx";
                myform.method = "post";
                form1.appendChild(product);
                document.body.appendChild(form1);
                form1.submit();
```

This will create a form and which has a child element product ("Input type") you have to append child element to parent element like product to form and form to DOM root elemnt body and document and you can add atribut of the form as action and method **this will do your thing.**

Comment: Not sure why you're creating `myform` and then later on using `form1`

Comment: how can I add params to the post function?