# Append javascript to HTML fields using through javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to create a form dynamically through javascript after looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991204/how-to-create-a-form-dynamically-using-javascript). Everything is going smoothly until when I attempt to insert javascript to the input form's value field. I am thinking of something like this

```
<input type = 'hidden' name = 'q' value = '<script>...some_script...</script>'
```

Here is my attempt at achieving what I want above

```
    my_form = document.createElement('form');
    my_form.name = 'form_A';
    ....

    my_tb = document.createElement('input');
    my_tb.type = 'hidden';
    my_tb.name = 'q';
    my_tb.id = 'query';
    my_tb.value = '<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>';

    my_form.appendChild(my_tb);
    document.body.appendChild(my_form);
    document.form_A.submit();
```

The problem is that something is wrong (or maybe even illegal) with the line `my_tb.value = '<script>alert(document.cookie)</script>';` When I run the file in my browser, it prints out all the javascript in the browser after that line, and in the developer console it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Is there a way to achieve what I want above while still using javascript to create **form_A** ? The main reason is what I was hoping I can store the value of `document.cookie` in a variable in javascript and use it later.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to insert the script in the input?

Comment: My course is learning how to conduct CSRF and XSS attacks, and one way of conducting XSS is to set the value of an input field as the "attack" script. In my scenario, my attempt at retrieving the cookies is the "attack script"

Comment: I think what your going for is `my_tb.value = document.cookie`

Comment: @DanielRasmuson then the value is simply `value='document.cookie'`, and is not injecting any scripts itself.

Comment: Try using ``</s>` + 'cript>'` for the closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

1. Create `index.html` file and paste the below.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
    // your site sets a cookie
    document.cookie="username=John Doe";

    my_form = document.createElement('form');
    my_tb = document.createElement('input');
    my_tb.value = document.cookie;
    my_form.appendChild(my_tb);
    document.body.appendChild(my_form);

    alert(my_tb.value);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

2. Run a server `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
3. Open `http://localhost:8000/`

Comment: This misunderstands what the OP is trying to do. He is trying to place the script tag as the value of the input field.